# How to get Site Map of ASP.NET page from where I am navigated to current page

Tags: development, asp.net, xml

I want breadcrumb trail from where I navigated to the current page and want to add an extra node to it.

For example:

I was here

`A > B > C > D > E (E has a link to Z)`

now I am here

`A > H > I > J > Z`

On Page `Z` I want a breadcrumb trail of links from where I navigated which should be `(A > B > C > D > E`) so that I can make it look like this (`A > B > C > D > E >` I will add this node)

I am using ASP.NET in SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using breadcrumb.

1) you need to add breadcrumb to every pages like this

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="mySiteMapDataSource" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" DataSourceID="mySiteMapDataSource" ParentLevelsDisplayed=6>
```

2) Then you need to add web.sitemap file by clicking on add new item--->site map--->the name should be web.sitemap.

**Note: No need to configure with sitemappath it will configure autometically.**

in that sitemap file you can write code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
  <siteMapNode title="A" description="Home" url="~/A.aspx">
    <siteMapNode title="B" description="B" url="~/B.aspx">
      <siteMapNode title="C" description="C" url="~/C.aspx" >
        <siteMapNode title="D" description="D" url="~/D.aspx" >
          <siteMapNode title="E" description="E" url="~/E.aspx" >
            <siteMapNode title="z" description="z" url="~/Z.aspx" >
          </siteMapNode>
        </siteMapNode>
      </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>

</siteMap>
```

I think it should work

Comment: thanks but I forgot to mention I have loads of same cases so I can't use static map, I must have to do coding in usercontrol

Comment: sorry I couldn't upvote your answer/effort because dont have enough reputation

Comment: Thanx..Happy Coding